# Adding a semicolon java netbeans

Tags: java

[image]

is this Considered an infinite loop?

Comment: CV is a site for questions about *statistics*. This doesn't appear to have anything to do w/ statistics. We can try to migrate it to [SO] for you. You should probably type the code, rather than have it as an image, though.

Comment: I agree with @gung that this shouldn't be  here.  Our site does entertain questions on statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining and data visualization.  But this doesn;'t fit.  Maybe it can be migrated to a different Stack Exchange site. I don't know what to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax-valid form can be considered an infinite loop, because it do not alter the loop condition in any way.

In the first example, if the semicolon is removed, then the loop will run ten times, since `i` has the ability to be incremented.

The second example won't compile, since a semicolon isn't permitted to be there, as it is an unreachable statement.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i=0; which is a constant value or no flow of i in while block so it is infinite but it does not contain any error.